# Create a page for each database table entries

Tags: customization, pages, templates, url-rewriting

I am creating a job board website(it is a part of the website). I have a `JobOffer` class with some rows in the database(added with it's form...). My problem now is to have a page for each of these JobOffers. I can't use it as a `WP_Post` because a want a custom rendering, i will need to add own data.
This is my idea:

- Create a page(from the wordpress dashboard -> Pages) with the name "Job Offer" and slug "job-offer"
- Set the link a `JobOffer` like `/job-offer?id={job_id}&label={job_label}`
- In the "Job Offer" page only add this shotcode: `[single-job-offer]`
- In the shortcode definition get the id (`$_GET['id']`) and the label(`$_GET['label']`) and render the content as i want
- Change the page url and page title in the browser with javascript:

```js
document.title = "The job title"
window.history.pushState("url_with_a_better_form");
```

But it is not a good [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413455/13808068).

Hoping i explain well what i want, what do you think i should do to follow SEO rules and have a page for all JobOffers, each of these pages having a title, a custom url and my shortcode as content.

**EDIT**:
I followed the links given and i created my custom post type:

```php
function phenix_custom_post_type()
{
    register_post_type(
        'phenix_job_offer',
        array(
            'labels'      => array(
                'name'          => 'Job Offers',
                'singular_name' => 'Job Offer',
            ),
            'public'      => true,
            'show_ui' => false,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'offres'
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'phenix_custom_post_type');
```

And my template(single-phenix_blue_color.php):

```php
<?php


get_header();
do_action('onepress_page_before_content'); // I'm working in my child theme and the parent is OnePress
?>

<div id="content" class="site-content">

    <?php onepress_breadcrumb(); ?>

    <div id="content-inside" class="container ">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'single'); ?>

                    <hr class="hr">
                    <?php
                    if (is_user_logged_in() && in_array('subscriber', _wp_get_current_user()->roles)) :
                        // 
                        if ($job_apps != null && count($job_apps) > 0) {
                            $tmp = array_filter($job_apps, function (JobApplication $elt) {
                                return is_int(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $elt->job->post_name));
                            });

                            if (count($tmp) > 0)
                                echo "<div class='mt-2 mb-3 h6'><span class='alert alert-info'>" . do_shortcode('[icon name="circle-info" prefix="fas"]') . " ...</span></div>";
                        }
                    ?>

                        <p class="h5 mb-3">...</p>
                        <?= do_shortcode('[form-job-application]') ?>

                    <?php else : ?>

                        <p class="h6">
                            ////
                            <?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
                                ///////
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </p>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </main>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Sorry for the length.
I manually created a post in the database with the `phenix_job_offer` type and it displays well. I am still thinking on how i can more customize the template but my problem is: How can i tell the template to not try to fetch the post in the database but use my post(a custom wp_post that i will create just for the rendering of my `JobOffer`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem. What have i done ?

- Create and register my custom post type, create a template for it (see my edit in the first message of the topic).
- Create a small code that creates a post for each of my jobOffers with these fields:

```php
// I also add this function in the `JobOffer` creation function so that the new ones will have a corresponding post
wp_insert_post([
   'post_content' => $jobOffer->description,
   'post_title' => $jobOffer->label,
   'post_excerpt' => substr($jobOffer->description, 75),
   'post_type' => 'phenix_job_offer',
   'post_name' => sanitize_title($jobOffer->label),
   'meta_input' => ['job_offer' => $jobOfferId]
]);
```

- After that in my template i fetch the jobOffer with the post meta key ‘job_offer’ then render it as i want.

```php
$post = get_post();

require_once('wp-content/themes/PhenixDOr-Plus/includes/repositories/repository-job-offer.php');
$jobOfferRepo = new JobOfferRepository();
$jobOffer = $jobOfferRepo->get(intval($post->job_offer));

// My template
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not work this way. At least it's not recommended to cook WordPress this way because it uses different concepts you won't see in most other CMS and frameworks.

It'd be better to create a custom post type. In this case, your job offer postings permalinks will look like this: site.com/job-offfer/...

In this case, you'll be able to use all the features that WordPress provides for custom post types: meta fields, template structure, etc.

You can learn more about custom post types and how to handle them here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/working-with-custom-post-types/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/

Comment: So i have to create a new Post type like `JobOffer` and create a custom template for it. I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Please i still have a problem. I want to keep my `JobOffers` and just use the wordpress post_types to help me for the display. I don't want to create, edit or delete my `JobOffers` with the wordpress "program".  I successfully create the post_type(thanks to your first link) but my work ends there. What should i do to render my `JobOffer` as if it was a custom_post without creating adding a custom post in database for all of my JobOffers ?